# ASP LITERAL not displaing HTML Code, it leave alot of code out

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

This is my code, I have to use the code behind because I need it to repeat over 5 different divs before looping, this is the first div

```
Public Sub LoadData()
        Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT top 5  FullName,Right(Articlename,10) ArticleName, Right(Article,50) AS ArticleSummary , Concat('../view/', Articles.ArticleID ) AS ArticleID, getdate() As Date, a.username , u.userid From ASpnetusers A inner join ArticleUser Ar on Ar.Userid = A.ID inner join Articles on Articles.ArticleID = AR.ArticleID join users u on u.id= a.id"
        ' Fire up SQLConnection with a DataReader
        Dim connection As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DefaultConnection").ConnectionString)
    Dim command As New SqlCommand(strSQL, connection)
        connection.Open()
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()


        Try

            Dim HtmlString As String

            While reader.Read()
                HtmlString = " <div class='cbp-item'>
                                        <div class='cbp-caption'>
                                            <!-- Blog Card -->
                                            <article class='card d-block border-0 transition-3d-hover mt-1'>
                                                <div class='card-body p-5'>
                                                    <!-- Header -->
                                                    <header class='d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-4'>
                                                        <a class='btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-soft-danger rounded-circle' href='javascript:;'>
                                                            <span class='fas fa-arrow-down btn-icon__inner'></span>
                                                        </a>
                                                       <SMALL class='text-muted'>  <asp:label class='text-muted' runat='server' Text='" & reader("date").ToString & " ' />   </SMALL>
                                                    </header> 
                                                    <div class='mb-4'>
                                                        <img class='img-fluid rounded' src='../../assets/img/500x280/img1.jpg' alt='Image Description'>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <h2 class='h5'>
                                                       <p><<asp:HYPERLINK class='text-muted' runat='server' TEXT='" & reader("ArticleName").ToString & " ' HREF='" & reader("Articleid").ToString & "'  >  </asp:HYPERLINK>   
                                                   </p> </h2>
                                                    <asp:HYPERLINK class='mb-0' runat='server' Text='" & reader("ArticleSummary").ToString & "' HREF='" & reader("Articleid").ToString & "' ></asp:HYPERLINK>
                                                    <!-- End Info -->
                                                </div>
                                                       <!-- Footer -->
                                                <footer class='card-footer p-5'>
                                                    <div class='media align-items-center'>
                                                        <a class='u-sm-avatar position-relative mr-1' href='#'>
                                                             <asp:Image runat='server' class='img-fluid rounded-circle'  ImageUrl='<%#""ShowImages.ashx?UserName=" & reader("UserName").ToString & " "" %>' alt='Image Description' />
                                                            <span class='badge badge-md badge-outline-primary badge-pos badge-pos--bottom-right rounded-circle'>&#43;</span>
                                                        </a>
                                                        <div class='media-body'>
                                                            <h3 class='h6 mb-0'>
                                                                <asp:hyperlink runat='server' Text='" & reader("fullname").ToString & "' href='<%#String.Format(""profile.aspx?UserID=" & reader("username").ToString & """) %>' ></asp:hyperlink>
                                                            </h3> 
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </footer>
                                                <!-- End Footer -->
                                            </article>

                                            <!-- End Blog Card -->
                                        </div>
                                    </div>"

                bodyrepeater1.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(HtmlString.ToString)


            End While
            connection.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

The webform

```
<asp:Literal ID="bodyrepeater1" runat="server" />
```

DOuble quotes appear as "& quot ;" I cant get double quotes to appear on the web page, once it goes through asp literal control it get converted

Comment: I guess you cannot have an `<asp:>` control inside a `Literal` HTML markup.

Comment: Looks like it, the code would good if it didnt have issues with the double quotes. Do you know what else I can use instead of a literal control? I couldnt use a repeater as I have 5 different html blocks and wasnt able to get the repeater to move to the next record, if I was able to get the repeater to move to the next record after each block it would be good but I dont know if thats possible

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try by removing HtmlDecode while assigning the value to literal.
i.e.

```
bodyrepeater1.Text =HtmlString.ToString
```